# How to automatically attach to multiple child processes while debugging native code on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, fork

For all its crashing, Visual Studio has some nice features. One of which is the ability to attach to process A, and automatically attach to all of process A’s child processes. (Using the child process debugging power tool)

Is there equivalent functionality using gdb, or other debugging tools on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

gdb does not have a built-in way to do this on `attach`.

It is possible to write one using a bit of gdb scripting; though I'm not sure the kernel keeps ancestry information for a process after its parent process exits -- meaning that in some cases any such approach could miss some grandchildren.